# Bot context.Wait not showing next message

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework

I am working on Bot application that have **IDialog**. When the increment value reaching 4 it is not calling **MessageEndAsync** and waiting for the user input. Without user input not showing next message in the Emulator.

I am looking some solution once the validation is passed then move to the next message otherwise keep checking the validation.

Could you pleas help me to fix the issue.

```
[Serializable]
    public class PlayGame: IDialog<object>
    {

        private int increment = 0;
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;
            increment++;
            if (increment == 4)
            {
                await context.PostAsync(increment.ToString());
                context.Wait(MessageEndAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync(increment.ToString());
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }
        public virtual async Task MessageEndAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Thanks for your information");
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`MessageEndAsync` won't be called until the user send an input. Instead of doing `context.Wait` just put the code within the if clause. So if the increment is 4, you will post the message and end the dialog.

`context.Wait` is used to put the bot in wait state for the upcoming user input.